# Netty: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError

Tags: netty

I am getting this problem:

```
io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 4194304 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 134217728, max: 134217728)
     at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.incrementMemoryCounter(PlatformDependent.java:845)
     at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:774)
     at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:701)
     at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:676)
     at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:215)
     at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.tcacheAllocateSmall(PoolArena.java:180)
     at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:137)
     at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:129)
     at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:396)
     at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
     at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
     at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:116)
     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.allocate(SslHandler.java:2267)
     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1348)
     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246)
     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)
     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:426)
     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:393)
     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:376)
     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1085)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
     at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelInactive(LoggingHandler.java:206)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:303)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813)
     at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
     at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
     at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

I am new to netty and I have no idea what the problem could be. This error is coming only time to time. In a performance test about 1 hrs, it occurs 3 times.